# Match a string between two same chars

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use back references in Java regex, but it seems I'm not doing it the right way and can't get it work. I wanted to be able to match parts of string surrounded by 2 same quotes, say find if a string contains **`"whatever"`** or **`'whatever'`**.

I then wrote the following code :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"|\')whatever\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher("'whatever'loremipsumblah");
System.out.println(m.find());   // always returns false
```

... but it seems the back reference is not working at all, as the matcher can't find any part of the string matching the pattern. I hope you guys will be able to help me cause I'm definitely stuck :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the backslash before the digit '1'. Otherwise the sequence "\1" is interpreted as an octal escape for the character U+0001.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"|\')whatever\\1");
```

Comment: I forgot it, don't know why, thought it would result in "\" char followed by one... Thanks for pointing my foolishness !

Comment: Unlike some languages, Java treats an unknown escape in a String literal as a syntax error.  So a literal '\' character in a String must always be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try "lookingAt" instead of "find". Something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"|\')whatever\\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"whatever\"");

if (m.lookingAt())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```